# How to auto grow text on input value?

Tags: javascript

I have an input form field that outputs text on submit to another created input, essentially an editable todo list. I have tried to make the input text value auto grow, but cannot figure out how to do it. Right now the user has to scroll over to see the rest of the text on each list item. This should not be.

What I tried:
I have tried creating a span and attaching editableContent but that makes my input text disappear.

I have tried setting an attribute on max-length on the created input but cannot get it to work. What is the best way to accomplish auto growing the text input value?
Here is the full [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/BaRddYx)

```
const createTodoText = (todo) => {
  const itemText = document.createElement("INPUT");
  // const itemText = document.createElement("span");
  // itemText.contentEditable
  // itemText.contentEditable = 'true'
  itemText.classList.add("todoText");
  itemText.value = todo.name;
  itemText.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  });
  // update todo item when user clicks away
  itemText.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    todo.name = e.currentTarget.value;
    renderTodos();
  });
  return itemText;
};
```

Comment: Hello Mate. Just a moment. Looking  into this.
Fingers crossed :)

Comment: ok, much appreciated :)

Comment: From HTML perspective this can't be done. But i am thinking of a hack. 
Let me see whether that would work.

Comment: Mate,I had understood the question wrongly. I guess Zaeem Khaliq has solved this for you. You can try his answer and accept the same if it works for you.

Cheers !!!

Comment: No worries, I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Deat Friend, My mind just thought a quick solution for this. If that works let me share. I actually misunderstood the question initially. I thought I have to make the text grow on newline within the field.

Comment: Well, initially growing with auto height would have been great, but for now growing horizontal would work as well. But sure, that would be great to see your solution! On the other solution, I noticed the blur changed where previously user would click out of list on the page and it would update. With the new solution the user has to click on the list item to update. Not sure why that changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235161/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-stephenw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go: -

```
// select DOM elements
const todoForm = document.querySelector(".todo-form");
const addButton = document.querySelector(".add-button");
const input = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const ul = document.getElementById("todoList");

let todos = [];

todoForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addTodo(input.value);
});

const addTodo = (input) => {
  if (input !== "") {
    const todo = {
      id: Date.now(),
      name: input,
      completed: false
    };
    todos.push(todo);
    renderTodos();
    todoForm.reset();
  }
};

const renderTodos = (todo) => {
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  todos.forEach((item) => {
    let li = document.createElement("LI");
    // li.classList.add('item');
    li.setAttribute("class", "item");
    li.setAttribute("data-key", item.id);
    const itemText = createTodoText(item);
    const cb = buildCheckbox(item);
    const db = buildDeleteButton(item);
    // if (item.completed === true) {
    //  li.classList.add('checked');
    // }
    li.append(cb);
    li.append(db);
    li.append(itemText);

    ul.append(li);
  });
};

const createTodoText = (todo) => {
  const itemText = document.createElement("span");
  itemText.setAttribute('role','textbox');
  itemText.setAttribute('contenteditable',"true");
  itemText.classList.add("todoText");
  itemText.innerHTML = todo.name;
  itemText.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  });
  // update todo item when user clicks away
  itemText.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
    todo.name = e.target.textContent;
    renderTodos();
  });
  return itemText;
};

const buildCheckbox = (todo) => {
    const cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cb.name = 'checkbox';
    cb.classList.add('checkbox');
    cb.checked = todo.completed;
    // checkbox not staying on current state ??
    cb.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
            // todo.completed = e.target.value;
      todo.completed = e.currentTarget.checked
            e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked');
        } 
    });
    return cb;
};

const buildDeleteButton = (todo) => {
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.className = "delete-button";
  deleteButton.innerText = "x";
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    // duplicates children sometimes ??
    const div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
    todos = todos.filter((item) => item.id !== todo.id);
  });
  return deleteButton;
};

// //------ Local Storage ------
function addToLocalStorage(todos) {}

function getFromLocalStorage() {}

// getFromLocalStorage();
```

This is the Javscript code part. In createTodoText, you can see the changes i've made. It's working according to what you want. What i've done is simple used 'span' instead of 'input'.

Comment: I appreciate you doing that. I am kind of thrown off now, how do I get rid of the undefined and change the logic?

Comment: @Zaeem Khaliq: Dear Friend, First of all Eid Mubarak to you and to your family.
The thing, simply changing an `input` to `span` doesn't help the OP as this is the todo application and we need an `input`  to edit any todo. 

So, we need to somehow find a way that input grows as the user types more than width of the input.

Comment: @StephenW Check now. I've edited the code

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq: Not working mate. The text still grows beyond the width of the input

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather This is not what OP asked for. He is asking for auto growing input text value. Not the width of the input.

Comment: @StephenW In span, we use event.target.textContent to get the value of the text that is written instead of event.target.value that we do for input. So, whenever you require value from this span, just remember this.
Also please do tell if the latest code is working for you or not.

Comment: Oh !!! OK, You mean as the text-within the input grows that of the width, the input field should grow accordingly. 
Great. Then I feel, your code isn't making it grow, I checked it mate

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Check the latest code please. Copy this code and paste it there at the CodePen.

Comment: Sure Mate. Let me check.

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq Looking fine Mate. Well Done.
I had understood the question wrongly actually. But, I think your solution looks fine.  However after editing the field with too much content, it kind of breaks. But first condition is met.

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq Sorry, I was occupied...It looks like you solved it, but I noticed before on blur, when user clicks out of list on page the item updates. Now, the blur only works if the list item (black background) is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like

> `if (todo.name.length) {itemText.size = todo.name.length;}`